# adding Cells (which never change) to UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

im trying to code a drumpad app for iOS. After a few battles with Interface Builder i decided to place the 4x4 grid of "pads" inside a Collection View.

Im using constrains to keep the CollectionView on top of the screen and also set KeepAspectRatio true so it will be a square on every screen.

I also created a single Cell with a UIButton and gave it a reusableIdentifier to be used for every Pad..

Now the idea is to use FlowLayout and just fill the View with the 16 cells and do some Math on the cell width to distribute them evenly across the CollectionView.

This is the first time im using XCode and Swift.. so i can't help but google for stuff, watch Youtube Videos and so on..

Following a Guide my code looks like this so far

```
extension DrumGridViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 16
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TriggerPad", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    // Configure the cell
    return cell
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let screenWidth = self.view.frame.width/4-5
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth);
    }
}
```

So up next would be for me to create a Datasource and so forth..
The thing is.. my DataSource is "static" if you will.. it will always be the Cells with UIButtons also.. the numberOfItemsInSection will also always be 16.. so im wondering if this method is a bit much for the thing i am trying to do.

So my Question is Cant this be done a eaasier? I tried to fiddle around but not having much success so far.

thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what do you want? Do you want 16 cells which never change? And You use those cells for what ?

Comment: I want to add the cells to my collectionView. the cells will hold a UIButton

Comment: so what do you want with button ?

Comment: im using the buttons to play audiofiles. the reason im using the CollectionView is to create the 4 by 4 button Grid. The buttons are fine though..adding the cells to the Collection is where i am having problems